# c++ assignment operator overloading of a non-member function

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, non-member-functions

I have a variable class that I am using to make scripting more easier in my program.  I am trying to figure out an easy way to do something like the following:

```
myclass
{
protected:
    int _data;
...
}
```

when I overload operators with non-member functions such as the following:

```
int operator+(const int, const myclass);
int operator+(const int lhs, const myclass rhs)
{
    return lhs + rhs.GetData();
}
```

I have no problems until I try to overload an assignment operator with a non-member function.

```
int operator=(const int, const myclass);
```

This gives an error and won't compile.
error C4430: Missing type specifier - int assumed.
errir C2801 'operator =' must be a non-static member.

I just want to be able to have something like the following work:

```
myclass A(7);
int B = 5;
int C;
C = B + A;
```

how can I achieve this.  I have tens of millions of lines of code that I just want to replace simple int's with myclass, but don't want to have to edit every use of this variable.

Note: edited to add error messages.

Final Edit:
Solution found:

```
operator int() const { return _data; }
```

By adding the overload operator, I have no need to overload the assignment operator as a non-member function.

Comment: _"This gives an error and won't compile."_ Please [edit] your question, and specify the exact error message.

Comment: Useful reference: [The basics of operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719#4421719). `operator=` as a non-member function is _very weird_. What are you trying to assign to? What's the return value? If you want to be able to write something like `int C = someMyClass + someInt;`, what you probably actually want is a conversion `operator int`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Comment: No The basics of operator overloading does not answer it.  But I did find a solution via overloading the typecast operation that did resolve the problem for me.